# How to Disable Format option on Logical Drives

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I want to Disable Format option on Logical Drives for others. Except me, Others should not format my Logical Drives.

Once when I gave my Laptop to friend, He formatted F-Logical Drive instead of PEN Drive by mistake. :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a new non-administrator account for your friend so that you can limit the damage he can do? I'm pretty sure you cannot format hard drives on Windows 7 if you do not have administrator privileges.